# Trouble showing modal manually with jQuery (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble showing my `bootstrap modal` manually with my `jQuery`code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
                <span class="closebtn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
                <br><br><br>
                <div valign="middle" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h4>You Have Reached Your Limit</h4>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

These are my script imports:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but it does not seem to work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you loaded both jQuery and the Boostrap JS?

Comment: what error you are getting..? can you provide the fiddle.?

Comment: @Peter just added my script tags that i am using (jquery is in file main.js)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed i am not getting any errors, i am just not getting any reaction from the browser

Comment: @Michael I tried your code in a JsFiddle. As long as jQuery and Boostraps JS have been loaded before you call modal('show') then it works. Check the fiddle in my answer, the dialog is shown there

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you add jquery and bootstrap libraries:

see the working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/jasny/ZcLSE/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed.</p>
                <p>Praesent sit amet porttitor magna, auctor feugiat tellus. Sed venenatis tortor turpis, vel vestibulum eros pulvinar et. Pellentesque hendrerit diam quis dui euismod tincidunt. Sed sit amet mauris ipsum. Integer in magna tellus. In tincidunt mi quis nunc gravida sollicitudin. Aliquam ac dui eget erat consequat volutpat in eu magna.</p>
                <p>Sed feugiat bibendum leo consequat convallis. Donec facilisis, turpis a scelerisque venenatis, felis diam dictum tortor, vitae imperdiet tortor ligula eu lectus. Donec iaculis semper elementum. Nullam dapibus porttitor magna quis convallis. Morbi porttitor quam non magna ullamcorper rhoncus. Phasellus sit amet nunc at turpis pharetra luctus a a massa. Praesent luctus massa in odio faucibus eleifend.</p>
                <p>In eget lobortis leo, ut luctus odio. Mauris pharetra erat ac tellus hendrerit semper. Cras faucibus ipsum id ante hendrerit rutrum. Donec vitae ullamcorper arcu. Aliquam pellentesque faucibus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. In tincidunt metus sit amet ligula sagittis vehicula. Pellentesque velit quam, hendrerit a erat ac, fermentum tincidunt enim. Cras suscipit justo nec consectetur lacinia.</p>
                <p>Cras pellentesque urna a leo egestas, at ullamcorper augue suscipit. Nulla id lacinia magna, non iaculis est. Praesent a placerat augue, eget eleifend purus. Aenean dignissim, orci et rutrum facilisis, tellus massa porta nulla, quis hendrerit dui ipsum vitae urna. In mattis lectus dolor, id venenatis lectus pellentesque at. Suspendisse posuere metus vel bibendum dignissim. Fusce interdum magna id libero scelerisque suscipit. Duis orci augue, rhoncus eget pharetra ac, viverra nec magna. In accumsan nulla ac suscipit pellentesque. Nulla iaculis luctus tellus, at ultricies urna hendrerit a. Aenean vehicula sodales varius. Duis sodales hendrerit odio non sagittis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/4c1uux9y/

```js
$('#openModal').click(function(){
  $('#modal').modal({show: true});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="openModal">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
        <span class="closebtn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
        <br><br><br>
        <div valign="middle" class="alert alert-danger"><h4>You Have Reached Your Limit</h4></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what you should do to open a modal
`$('#modal').modal({show: true});`

Ordering of the file should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Updated answer** for dynamic button added

```
$(document).on('click', '#openModal', function(){
  $('#modal').modal({show: true});
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this seems to work, but it still does not work when adding it to my code, i added the "openModal" id to my existing button, but it does not work on my end

Comment: @Michael is your button `openModal` is dynamically getting added?

Comment: no, it is in the page to start with, i am getting no errors, but when i click the button, nothing is happening

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: @Michael Is your situation is something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4c1uux9y/1/  ?

Comment: perhaps my problem is with the order in which i include my external files into my html, i am still not getting any response from the button after using the order your specified above

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but maybe you are calling `$('#modal').modal('show');` before jQuery and boostrap js have been loaded. Make sure to run your code in document ready or last in your file.

See your code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/ptornhult/k1k5qay8/

Answer (score 0):

Are your references for both **javascript** and **css** files inside `<body></body>` tags? If they are, please include your **css** between `<head></head>` tags. Maybe **css** is causing the issue and not **jQuery**. 
If that doesn't work, try to create your modal on top of your `<body></body>` tags. Sometimes modals don't show correctly when they are somewhere between.